# Run a TCP and looped process in python

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

I am trying to build an IoT device and looking forward to build something like this:

Schematic:

1. A python process which runs as a loop to interact with hardware components
2. A TCP server(Pub-Sub) which takes commands from its clients and pass on to (1)
3. (1) can interact with (2) to publish an event and (2) can interact with (1) to control the hardware

Here is what I tried:

1. Using twisted, I created a pub sub service
2. tried to command that service to emit events
3. TCP listener on a Node.js serever to interact with Twisted TCP server

This is what I observed:

Node.js server is able to send messages to Twisted server properly.

Twisted blocks executing other code (Schematic:1) after calling `reactor.run()` as it starts listening on a port.

I would like to have both the process run simultaneously and interact with each other.

Is there a way to achieve this without using multithread or multiprocesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `asyncio`

We can run 2 loops which can be asynchronous, with `asyncio.sleep` in both the loops so other loop gets its turn to execute.

python docs also has a tcp server example with asyncio, so there that solved my requirement